# How to Create Scatter plot inside the Circle in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Suppose I have a data which entails the population who are living in a particular tenure are whether in poverty or not.

```
Tenure Type   In Poverty    Not in Poverty 
Tenure_A      45786        784733
Tenure_B      98453        359584
Tenure_C      34954        385884
Tenure_D      29586        948434
Tenure_E      74854        385869
```

Tenure type has 5 categories and whether the number people living in any particular tenure type are considered under poverty or not, are given. Now, I wanted to make a Scatter plot stacked in a circular shape with two rings; inner and outer. Every single dot inside the inner ring will be considered under poverty status, so consider that inner circle as a threshold (Any arbitary threshold). And everyone in the outer ring will be not in poverty. Also, imp. to note, Suppose Tenure_A have 45,786 people living in the Poverty Status so I need 45,786 individual dots inside the inner ring and same for all categories.

I am bit confused as to how to move forward here. How shall I proceed with this? Thanks.

I tried with GGplot2, but not getting results as expected.

Code which I used -

```
    ggplot(data = Poverty) + 
      geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = In_Poverty, y = Tenure_Type, 
                                color = Tenure_type)) + 
      coord_polar()
```

Comment: What did you try? Pls include code example.

Comment: How do you anticipate showing hundreds of thousands of dots in a visualization? How large will your visualization be and how many pixels should a "dot" be?

Comment: In theory, you could do this using `tidyr::uncount` to make 45,786 into that many rows of observations, you could use ggplot with geom_jitter + coord_polar to get dots spread in rings. But I don't think there's a good way to represent numbers this big without making each dot represent like 100 or 1000 people.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks for the comment. Yes, I would be doing the same to represent each dot for 1000 people. So, how shall I make each point represent 1000's people because with ggplot it is just representing the whole population as a single point? I am editing the post with the code I used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first pass without any formatting tweaking:

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       Tenure.Type = c("Tenure_A","Tenure_B",
                       "Tenure_C","Tenure_D","Tenure_E"),
        In.Poverty = c(45786L, 98453L, 34954L, 29586L, 74854L),
    Not.in.Poverty = c(784733L, 359584L, 385884L, 948434L, 385869L)
) -> Poverty

library(tidyverse)
Poverty %>%
  pivot_longer(-Tenure.Type) %>%
  uncount(round(value/1000)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(1, name, color = Tenure.Type)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much, this is what I was looking. Also, is there a way to increase the surface area or the radius of the outer ring?